# Optical path difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, refraction

[image]

I have question about calculating optical path difference.
$$\Delta L = \mathrm{(BC+CD)}\cdot n_2 - \textrm{BF}\cdot n_1$$ - why calculating path difference here we are subtracting $\mathrm{BF}$ segment?

Comment: It's (BC + CD) * n2  - BF * n1

Comment: because we assume that our lens is perpendicular to the reflected rays (i.e. parallel to DF). so the blue line should be parallel to DF.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this fully, you really need to be thinking of rays as *normals to wavefronts*. In this representation, a ray's tail gets assigned by a phase factor to represent the total phase of the plane wave. This phase factor advances by $2\,\pi\,\times$ an amount calculated by multiplying the distance advanced along the wavefront, in wavelengths, by the medium's refractive index if you move along the ray. But if you move orthogonal to the ray, you're still on the same phase front. Therefore, in this representation, a ray can be slidden along the wavefront, *i.e.* in a direction normal to the ray, whilst keeping the ray's direction constant, *without changing the wavefront it represents*. The phase factor assigned to its tail stays constant with this sideways sliding.

The rays through BF and DE represent plane waves in the same direction, just with different phases. Give the wavefront normal comments above, slide DE's tail to overlay it on BF without changing its direction, and the total expression should become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The result is "easy", but it is good to show the steps so that it can be understood. You know that the optical path is defined as the product $n\cdot s$ for a certain path of rays.

There is a single ray until $B$, so it is in phase with itself. Then, the ray splits and both "branches" follow different paths.

After the process, $DE$ and its parallel through $F$ (shall we call it $FG$?) keep going to infinity, parallel and along the same medium. It's obviously no path difference in those two rays. We are tracing the perpendicular ($DF$) between two points. That distance is then mantained afterwards, so the difference acquired keeps constant because those two rays follow parallel along the same path.

Consequently, the only delay is caused only by the differences between $BF$ and $BCD$. The optical path of the inner ray is $n_2\cdot(BC+CD)$, whiel the reflected one is only $n_1\cdot BF$ until it reaches the common path.

Obliously the difference between them is the increment of optical path.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, BC > BF. Therefore $(BC + CD) * n2 - BF * n1$ will never be 0 (n2 > n1, given). There will always be a phase difference in ray F and ray E.

Answer (score 0):

The incident wavefront is divided in amplitude at B.
The apparatus is arranged to collect parallel rays after reflection by using an optical system focussed at infinity.
In effect this means that you are observing the difference in phase between waves at $F$ and $D$, line $FD$ being perpendicular to the rays, when those waves overlap/superpose/interfere in the focal plane of the optical system.

Answer (score 0):

The optical path difference (difference in phase) is the total phase accumulated by one wave, minus the phase accumulated by the other.

So while one part of the wave goes into the second medium, by the time it "catches up with" the part of the wave that was reflected off the first interface it has accumulated a phase (optical other) corresponding to the path inside medium 2. When compared to the first wave, it has traveled the distance BF by the time the two rays are parallel again.